# Upload new items to table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have table view that load new data (depend on page) from SQL data base. Problem is, when i load it in main thread, it block UI for a while. When i try to do "hard work" in background, and reload data in main thread, odd things start to happen, for example, table view section header move in wrong place, and i load enormous amount of data.

First case, all work but block UI for while:

```
   [self.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
        @strongify(self)

        if (!self.viewModel.isUpdating){

            self.viewModel.isUpdating = YES;
            [self.tableView.infiniteScrollingView startAnimating];
            [self.viewModel nextPage];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            self.viewModel.isUpdating = NO;   
        }

    }];
```

In second case, i tried to do background work, following not work as expected:

```
if (!self.viewModel.isUpdating){


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //Add some method process in global queue - normal for data processing

     self.viewModel.isUpdating = YES;
     [self.tableView.infiniteScrollingView startAnimating];
        [self.viewModel nextPage];


       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            //Add method, task you want perform on mainQueue
            //Control UIView, IBOutlet all here
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            self.viewModel.isUpdating = NO;

        });

        //Add some method process in global queue - normal for data processing

    });




}

}];
```

How should i modify my code to not load main thread, and without "weird" things?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
.....
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
            });
        });
......
-(void)updateView{
[self.tableView reloadData];
self.viewModel.isUpdating = NO;
}
```

user PerformSelectorOnMainThread it may help you.